# How to create a slider that increments values in real-time

Tags: delphi, slider, real-time

I'm tasked with a project of creating a program running under Windows for a charity in Delphi (7 or XE3). I want to create a smooth slider similar to that of the screen brightness adjuster on iPhone, only that it should increment the value of money that the user wishes to donate to the charity.

The main goal is to adjust the value while the user is dragging the slider instead of just updating it when the user releases the slider.

Is there a built-in component with this feature?

(PS: I am in my final year of high school, so it would be greatly appreciated if it is put as simple as possible.)

Comment: Anyway, wouldn't it be easier to let the user type in how much money they want to donate.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you are developing a VCL application for Windows (neither Delphi 7 nor XE3 are targeting iPhones), you can use a standard TTrackbar and adjust the money value in the OnChange event.

Comment: Yes it is for a VCL application, the reference to iPhone was simply to describe how I would like it to look. thank you I will try that.